# How do I make asp.net model collection properties null if not posted in json

Tags: ajax, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this controller method:

```
public JsonNetResult Save(MyModel provider)
{
    return GetJson(_serviceProviderService.Save(provider));
}
```

I post this json (captured via Fiddler):

```
{"Id":100,"Name":"Foo", "CreatedDate":"2013-02-20T15:32:07.85", "Models":null}
```

When reaching the Save method in the controller (breakpoint) the property Models has become an an empty collection.

I want to keep the null value on the Models property. How do I do that?

Reason: I want treat the null value as the Models collection was not "loaded" and will not be affected when saving the object graph; It should only be affected when it contains items.

Here is the ViewModel:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public List<EntityDisplayNameModel> Models { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: can you tell why you want it to be null?

Comment: I've written the reason in the post, If the collection is empty I want the all Model that are connected to "MyModel" database to be deleted. If the Models collection is null I don't want the Models to be touched. Null means that the Models collection for MyModel was not loaded in the GUI.

Comment: Just omit the `"Models":null` from the json data (assuming you don't have a parameterless constructor that initializes `Models`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Yes, that works. I guess that if you wrote your comment as an answer I would accept it. (if noone else have a better solution :) )

Comment: It works to recieve null on collections if I put the Save method in an ApiController instead (asp.net web api)